# $_GET[id_row] in another DIV with javascript goTo url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem.
Need to pass and ID to open more data in other DIV on same page

The classical proceeding I usually do is:

```
<a href="page_name.php?id=<?php echo $result['id_row']; ?>
```

And in the page_name pick up the ID

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_row='".$_GET['id']."'");
```

But... I am working in a HTML5 template and I need do show data on same page in another DIV using jquery.

```
<a href="javascript:goTo('div_article_name');">Show More</a></li>
```

How can I identify the id to show more data in de div_article_name? Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: it would be better if you change your title to your problem statement - that code snippet doesn't say much about the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "data" attribute to your link tag `<a href="javascript::goToArticle('div_name')"> data-id="<?php echo $result['id_row']?>">` then you can get jquery like `$('a').data('id')`

Comment: `<a href="javascript:goTo('fullnews');" data-id="<?php echo $result['id_news']?>;"/>Read more</a>`




How can I GET the id_news in DIV fullnews using your sugestion?



`<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id_news='".$_GET['id']."'");    $result_news=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>`

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question. When you fetch the array you will have the ID in there $result_news['id']. if you want to get it via javascript you can use jquery like i said before.

Comment: Yes is what I want to do, but I never do this before... 
Can You link me an example?  
thanks